# Is there a way to increase the screen brightness of a macbook running snow leopard beyond what apple lets you?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, macbook, display, brightness

Any way to tweak it?  I'm guessing no, but I wouldn't have ever thought of overclocking a cpu would work either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt it. You'd have to somehow increase the brightness of the LEDs (or CCFLs) that constitute the backlight, and I doubt simply over-volting them would work. The only way I can think of would be to install more LEDs, but that is non-trivial.

What is the specific situation that requires a brighter screen? Maybe someone here can come up with a different solution that would work. (I tend to have the opposite problem: the screen is often too bright for me, even at the lowest setting.)

Comment: just when it's sunny outside and I want to work there.  the sun always makes the screen look dark.

Comment: @marty Yeah, I know how that is. Is there a way you can put the monitor in a dark corner (maybe with a shade?) while you're still in the sun?

Comment: @marty I had some semi-good experience sitting with my back to the sun and a glossy (or even no-glare) screen on minimum brightness.